# How to SET !VAR1 EVAL in javascript iMacros

Tags: javascript, firefox, match, eval, imacros

my iim code is:

```
SET 1 EVAL("var m = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\b33\\b/ig); if (!m) 'ok'; else 'not';")
```

I want to make it as JS. like this: (but give me error)

```
macro += "SET 1 EVAL("var m = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\b33\\b/ig); if (!m) 'ok'; else 'not';")" + "\n";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
macro += "SET 1 EVAL(\"var m = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\\b33\\b/ig); if (!m) 'ok'; else 'not';\")" + "\n";
```

You need to escape the double-quote characters that delimit the string being passed into the EVAL command. (c.f. [Note #5](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL#Notes))

Comment: Thank you, its work without error! but its give me always 'ok', the 'else' function not working for 'not'. what the problem?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer this second question, specifically, what is the value of !EXTRACT. Without knowing that value, it is not possible to determine the exact problem. Plus, I think you should mark the original question as answered and post this as a new question.